# How did an advancing force walk during WW1?

Tags: military, world-war-one, tactics

I am searching for any noticeable orders, doctrine or any piece of information about how an advancing force should be organized. I am interested in the scope 1914-1918, on European and Middle-East fronts.

By "advancing force", I mean:

- A force of varying size (battallion, brigade, division)
- That is advancing in an open ground and not in enemy fortifications
- That had passed first enemy lines.

So the question is **not** about:

- Attack or defence tactics
- Strategic movements

But I am really interesting in how a group of soldiers should advance between two fights, when it is not certain of the position of enemy forces: position in the column of cavalry, artillery, infantry, tanks...

For example:

What was the march order of the French and Serbian infantry after the breakthrough of Salonique?
How did Germans or Russians organize their marchs on the Eastern Front?
How did British army walked in Mesopotamia?

**EDIT:**

To clarify the question:
Imagine a situation where two armies are, on a strategic plan, closing with each other. Soldiers will come for example by railroad. When they disembark from the station, they adopt a *formation* and start moving in the forest/mountains/fields. Suddendly, an enemy is seen or sudden fire falls of the column. Orders are given and the *formation* is broken into tactical moves.

I am interested in what the *formation* was, in order to minimize damages (in an ambush for example) and maximize the speed of an attack (if enemy is discovered).

Comment: It's not clear to me that your question makes any sense. The *mobility* - meaning ability to move under enemy fire - of infantry and cavalry was essentially zero for all of WW1. Once trench warfare was established following the late summer *Race to the Sea* in France, all movement was always under fire unless a friendly artillery barrage (by 155 mm howitzers with a range of 11 km) was suppressing enemy fire. "*Infantry Attacks*" by Erwin Rommel is informative. See also [Vimy Ridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Vimy_Ridge).

Comment: [This article](https://warontherocks.com/2018/08/how-the-u-s-military-learned-to-learn-in-world-war-i-lessons-from-the-american-expeditionary-forces/) on how the Americans learned, reluctantly, from the English and French in late '17 and early '18 is good also.

Comment: @LаngLаngС: Possibly - I have only a passing familiarity with that front.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Sorry, but you 're out of the scope of the question. First, I did mention that I am interested in more than Western Front. Second, I did mention I am not speaking of tactical movements (as you say: move under ennemy fire), but rather movements between clashes and exchanges of fire

Comment: @LаngLаngС I meant exactly what you said: Advance in ennemy territory with close ennemy forces. But not already under fire. The example you gave are what I am interested in. I will edit

Comment: Usual method would be marching in columns. Nothing particularly special in this, armies use this from times immemorial till present. When contact with enemy occurs, they would deploy simply spread out, take cover, prepare for charge or defense etc ...

Comment: @totalMongot  you say this is not a question about tactics.. but isn't that exactly what you are asking?  "doctrine or any piece of information about how an advancing force should be organized"?  Movement on the battlefield is **[TACTICS](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/tactics)**... **(1)** the art or science of disposing military or naval forces for battle and maneuvering them in battle.
**(2)** the maneuvers themselves.
**(3)** any mode of procedure for gaining advantage or success.

Comment: @JMS Call it tactics or not, I trust you. You understand my question? Good :)

Comment: If I were to answer this question I would reference the cult of offense and the accepted military doctrine that offense always had the advantage in battle,  and any defensive action was ultimately self defeating;  and how this dominant military theory just failed to acknowledge modern innovations like barb wire and machine guns.

Comment: creeping barrage? https://www.thoughtco.com/the-creeping-barrage-of-ww1-theory-and-practice-1222116

Answer (score 1):

Callwell, [Small Wars](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/23/Small_Wars-_Their_principles_and_practice_%28C._E._Callwell%29.pdf). Only a few years before your time window. Flying columns in chapter 11.

USMC, Infantry in Battle. Written after your time window, but a retrospective. Googling only got me a PDF with half the text, perhaps you can find it in a library. Chapter 19 or thereabouts.

Answer (score 0):

John Schindler's *The Fall of the Double Eagle* has some information on this for the Gaillician and Serbian fronts, especially in 1914.  It's scattered throughout descriptions of the campaigns, though, rather than focused on doctrine, so it may not be quite what you are looking for.